# why does python store numbers up to 256 at static points in memory?

Tags: python, pointers, memory

Why does python store all the numbers up to 256 or 2^8 at static points in memory?

```
>>> id(2**8) == id(2**8), id(2**8+1) == id(2**8+1)
(True, False)
```

Comment: CPython interpreter optimization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong): *The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.*